# how to get value from sender option of uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

i created a custom table view cell with a button on it and targetof the button in the same file tableviewcell.m(base calsee UITableViewCell).

When i click on the button then action is get called .

what i have to do is to get the value from the sender option of that button.like shown in the figure want to get value of "badgesname".

[image]

Comment: what u want is get the value of the label in the cell that contain that button am i correct?

Comment: yes i want to get value of the label name "badgesname"

Comment: Oh my.. Store everything separately. What you should do is to fallow delegation pattern and save your data in cell too. Then, when buttons pressed, you call delegate method with self (from cell) and outside the cell you can take your cell's data.

Answer (score 1):

What you should when you want to track some additional events from cells, not only default selection. For example you add some buttons.

- Using `UIView`'s `tag` property is **bad**! *It's not easy to read code with tags. What will you do when you have not only rows but sections too?*
- Finding `UITableViewCell` as
  `superview` of your button is **bad too**! *Button can be added as direct `UITableViewCell` subview or as cell's `contentView` subview.*
- Don't try to determine cell by checking touch point, it's **bad**! *No comments..*
- Don't use associated objects here, it's **really bad**! *You can read article about runtime anti-pattens here: http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/*

So what should we do? We should follow **delegation pattern**. It's **good** for scaling too. You can store links to any data you want in your cell.

Your cell's header:

```
@class CellWithButton;

@protocol CellWithButtonDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)cellWithButtonDidPressed:(CellWithButton *)cell;

@end

@interface CellWithButton : UITableViewCell

@property id anyData;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CellWithButtonDelegate> *delegate;

@end
```

Your cell's implementation:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate cellWithButtonDidPressed:self];
}
```

Now your controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView cellFor...
{
    CellWithButton *cell = ...;
    cell.anyData = myData;
    cell.delegate = self;
}

- (void)cellWithButtonDidPressed:(CellWithButton *)cell
{
    id myData = cell.anyData;
    // Wow! Now you have your data.
    // And you can even find `indexPath` for your cell
    // by calling [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].
}
```

Comment: your answer is correct. but I think you should provide more explanation not only code

Comment: @sage444 should I add something?

Comment: No, In my opinion you just improved right answer to really good and informative one

Answer (score 0):

you can get whole cell by doing this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[button superView] superView];
```

then you can get your objects like this

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1234];
```

Comment: is there any problem... please tell me so i can update myself.

Comment: Look at my answer, I'll extend it.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the button action, convert the point of the button to the tableview's indexPath, then u can use that indexPath to get the value from your data array or even the cell

```
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
       //Do stuff with the data array
       //Object *obj = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
       //Get the text from the array

       //OR

       //YourCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
       //NSString *labelString = cell.textLabel.text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Donot create target method in tablviewcell.m file.Just create an outlet of button and add target in base controller from where your are creating table and follow the process as decribed.
In You cellForRowAtIndexPath: method give button a tag with indexPath.row and in button's action method just get tag and call cellForRowAtIndexPath to get cell.By cell you can fetch all values

```
 -(void)BtnOfCellTapped:(id)sender
 {
     UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
     CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:btn.tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.badgeValue);
 }
```

Comment: what you think will happens if table has more that one section

Answer (score 0):

You can use Associated Objects for this.

How to use Associated Objects?

**To set a property**

`objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"AnyString", object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);`

**To get a property**

`objc_getAssociatedObject(self,@"AnyString");`

For reference : http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/